# sort function in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to write a code to display a table using ajax call and sort the columns when the button is clicked. It seems like i am making error in the sort function but unable to solve it and the whole column is getting replaced with the smallest value of the age.I also have doubt in the display part.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http.css" >
    </head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <body>
        <table id="link" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Place</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <script>
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                    parsedfun(obj);
                }
            };
            req.open("GET", "xml.txt");
            req.send();

            function parsedfun(obj) {
                var out = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    out = out + '<tr><td class="namesort">' + obj[i].name + '</td><td class="agesort">' + obj[i].age + '</td><td class="placesort">' + obj[i].place + '</td></tr>';
                    $("#link").html(out);
                    $(".clk").click(function() {
                        $.getJSON("xml.txt", function(obj) {
                            $("td").each(function(index, value) {
                                obj.sort(function(a, b) {
                                    if (a.age < b.age) {
                                        return 1;
                                    } else {
                                        return -1;
                                    }
                                });
                                $(".agesort").html(obj[index].age);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        </script> 
        <button class="clk">sort the age</button>
        <div class="division">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the "xml.txt" file

```
[{
    "name": "x",
    "age": 21,
    "place": "Hyderabad"
}, {
    "name": "y",
    "age": 28,
    "place": "Chennai"
}, {
    "name": "z",
    "age": 20,
    "place": "Coimbatore"
}, {
    "name": "a",
    "age": 19,
    "place": "Kolkata"
}, {
    "name": "b",
    "age": 22,
    "place": "Mumbai"
}, {
    "name": "c",
    "age": 16,
    "place": "Mangalore"
}]
```

Comment: Side note: The compare function should return `0` rather than `-1` if the ages are equal.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly, you're setting the `html()` of the `table` which is wiping out the `thead` row. Use `append()` instead.

You also can use a single delegated event handler on the button. Your current code attaches a new event to that button for every single object in the array, which is redundant.

Lastly when you do the sorting you don't need to make another AJAX request as you can simply take the data you've got in the table and sort that. Try this:

```
function parsedfun(obj) {
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        out = out + '<tr><td class="namesort">' + obj[i].name + '</td><td class="agesort">' + obj[i].age + '</td><td class="placesort">' + obj[i].place + '</td></tr>';
    }
    $("#link").append(out);
}

$(document).on('click', '.clk', function() {
    $('#link tr').sort(function(a, b) {
        var aAge = parseInt($(a).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10);
        var bAge = parseInt($(b).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10);
        return aAge < bAge ? -1 : aAge > bAge ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo('#link')
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9s5hL2a8/)

Also note that your `<script>` tag should also be placed in the `<head>` or just before the `</body>`, and it's a little odd to call the file `xml.txt` when it's returning JSON.

To make things simpler you could use jQuery for the AJAX request as you're already using it for element events and selections.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON('xml.txt', function(data) {
            var out = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                out = out + '<tr><td class="namesort">' + obj[i].name + '</td><td class="agesort">' + obj[i].age + '</td><td class="placesort">' + obj[i].place + '</td></tr>';
            }
            $("#link").append(out);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.clk', function() {
            $('#link tr').sort(function(a, b) {
                var aAge = parseInt($(a).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10);
                var bAge = parseInt($(b).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10);
                return aAge < bAge ? -1 : aAge > bAge ? 1 : 0;
            }).appendTo('#link')
        });
    });
</script>
```